# Problema ao alterar usando pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para a faculdade e estou tendo o seguinte problema

> ```
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Disciplina in C:\Users\lucas.vianna\Desktop\SGA\db\turmaDAO.php on line 64
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: getDisciplina in C:\Users\lucas.vianna\Desktop\SGA\turmas.php on line 41
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Method name must be a string in C:\Users\lucas.vianna\Desktop\SGA\turmas.php:41 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\lucas.vianna\Desktop\SGA\turmas.php on line 41
> ```

---

Linha 41:  `$disciplina = $resultado->$getDisciplina();`
Linha 64: `$turma->setDisciplina($rs->Disciplina);`

---

Segue o código do update na *DAO*:

```
     public function atualizar($turma){
        global $pdo;
        try {
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT idTurma, Disciplina_idDisciplina,Nome FROM turma WHERE idTurma = :id");
            $statement->bindValue(":id", $turma->getIdTurma());
            if ($statement->execute()) {
                $rs = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $turma->setIdTurma($rs->idTurma);
                $turma->setDisciplina($rs->Disciplina);
                $turma->setNome($rs->Nome);
                return $turma;
            } else {
                throw new PDOException("Erro: Não foi possível executar a declaração sql");
            }
        } catch (PDOException $erro) {
            return "Erro: ".$erro->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Segue o codigo do select na view

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["act"]) && $_REQUEST["act"] == "upd" && $id != "") {

    $turma = new turma($id, '','');

    $resultado = $object->atualizar($turma);
    $nome = $resultado->getNome();
    $disciplina = $resultado->$getDisciplina();
}



<select name="disciplina"><?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Disciplina order by Nome;";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    if ($statement->execute()) {
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        foreach ($result as $rs) {
            if ($rs->idDisciplina == $disciplina) {
                echo "<option value='$rs->idDisciplina' selected>$rs->Sigla</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value='$rs->idDisciplina'>$rs->Sigla</option>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new PDOException("Erro: Não foi possível executar a declaração sql");
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: A propriedade *Disciplina* na linha `$rs->Disciplina` não existe. O correto é `$rs->Disciplina_idDisciplina`

Comment: E não é necessário o cifrão `$` para chamar um método, exceto se você usar uma variável com o nome do método, por exemplo: `$getDisciplina = "getDisciplina"; $resultado->$getDisciplina()`

Comment: Funcionou obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Disciplina : Significa que a Classe não esta definida;
Notice: Undefined variable: getDisciplina : Derivado do primeiro erro, obviamente se a classe não esta definido os metodos tambem não;
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Method name must be a string : Provavelmente estas a criar uma função com um nome invalido com caracteres especias ou numero:
PHP Function Names: Nunca deve iniciar com caracteres especias ou numero, exemplos: "{$, #, %, 1}".

E em relação ao global $pdo não é uma boa pratica ter uma classe com a conexão ao bannco de dados de uma forma global.

Considero a criação de uma Classe Singleton:

```
class DBConnection{
   private static $instance;
   private function __constructor(){}
   private function __clone(){}

   public function getDBaseConnection(){
      if(!isset(static::$instance)){
          $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
          static::$instance = new PDO(paramters, $pdo_options);
      }

      return static::$instance;
   }
```

}

```
$conneciton  = DBConnection::getDBaseConnection();
$connection->query(param);
```

//Vai ser a mesma classe a ser usada no projecto todo e so precisar ser instanciada; Caso queiras algo mais flexivel como por exemplo usar outro branco de dados tens a opção de passar o nome do banco como parametro para o metodo getDBaseConnection($dbName);

Comment: As explicações do primeiro parágrafo estão completamente equivocadas e seu código está incorreto.

Comment: A ideia era ajudar. E qual é o erro no código?

Comment: O erro foi corrigido, era na palavra `static`. Entendo que a ideia é ajudar.